# ssh refuses to authenticate keys

Tags: ssh, virtualbox, fedora, centos

So I am setting up a connection between my machine [fedora 17] and a virtual machine running in Virtual Box in which is running CentOS 5.
I have installed openssh from the repositories on CentOS, and I have configured everything as it follows:

```
Protocol 2

HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key

SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV

PermitRootLogin yes

RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile  /home/pigreco/.ssh/authorized_keys

PasswordAuthentication no

ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes

GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes

UsePAM yes

AcceptEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
AcceptEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
AcceptEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL LANGUAGE
AcceptEnv XMODIFIERS

X11Forwarding yes

Subsystem   sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
```

this is the configuration file sshd_config on the server i.e. on the CentOS. 
Moreover I have created a public/private key pair as usual on the .ssh/ folder in my home directory in my OS, i.e. Fedora, and then I've copied with scp the id_rsa.pub to the server and then I have appended its content to the file .ssh/authorized_keys on the server machine.

The error that I get is the following:

```
OpenSSH_5.9p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0j-fips 10 May 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 50: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.100.13 [192.168.100.13] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/mayhem/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /home/mayhem/.ssh/identity-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/mayhem/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/mayhem/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/mayhem/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/mayhem/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 16:e5:72:d1:37:94:1b:5e:3d:3a:e5:da:6f:df:0c:08
debug1: Host '192.168.100.13' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/mayhem/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Cannot determine realm for numeric host address

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Cannot determine realm for numeric host address

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information


debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Cannot determine realm for numeric host address

debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/mayhem/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
Agent admitted failure to sign using the key.
debug1: Trying private key: /home/mayhem/.ssh/identity
debug1: Trying private key: /home/mayhem/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
```

Do you have some good suggestion of what I can do?
thank you

Answer (score 2):

`ssh-agent` tries to sign the communication using your private key, but fails. If you didn't already do that, try running `ssh-add` to add the private key to the agent (run without arguments the command automatically tries to load the default key files). If you did alread load the key, try `export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=0`.

Comment: with the ssh-add I get `ssh-add
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.` and if I run ssh-agent `ssh-agent 
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-JSptucPy5585/agent.5585; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=5586; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 5586;
`

Comment: I tried also to delete the keys, making new keys without password, then changing and setting the permission of .ssh to 0700 and .ssh/authorized_keys to 0600, both server side and client side for .ssh...
But still it does not work...

Comment: Did you try to `export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=0`?

Comment: yes... no success... what export does btw?

Comment: `export` exports variables to the environment, so that the variables are available in other shells as well. Without using `export` a variable is only available in the current shell (and its children).

Comment: Try terminating all `ssh-agent` processes (`killall ssh-agent`).

Comment: I did it actually, but nothing changed. I actually installed Ubuntu 12.04 server and installed ssh server in it. It works like a charm... maybe it's some problem with CentOS...

Answer (score 1):

Any particular reason you're hard coding the location for your authorized_keys file?  OpenSSH is very anal about the permissions of files and their parent directory.  The server also does NOT tell the client why a key was rejected.  Check out your log file and see why sshd is rejecting the key.  Check for one of these files:  `/var/log/secure` or `/var/log/auth.log` on the server.  You will need root access.

Comment: Also, is it your intention to use ssh-agent?  If not, there's nothing wrong with disabling it for troubleshooting purposes.  This will allow you to determine if it's a problem with ssh-agent or something else.

Comment: had a similar issue. /Var/log/secure revealed that /root folder had wrong permissions. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

restorecon -R $user/.ssh

https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=8990